# Histogram plot in Matlab with constraints

Tags: matlab, plot, histogram

I want to plot a histogram with the following outputs:

```
   (a). number of bin
   (b). data in each bin
   (c). bin size for each bin
   (d). bin start & bin end for each bin
```

Each bin must have at least 7 elements. I gave a try something like this

```
  data = rand(100,1);
  n = hist(data);
```

This will give result like this

```
  10     8    12    12    10     3    10    12    12    11
```

When I tried

```
  n = hist(data,7);
```

I got

```
  15    14    17     9    11    16    18
```

& this is exactly what I want, with at least 7 elements in each bin! & at the same time I also want to cover part (c) & (d).

So, to be already sure that I am getting the right number of elements in each bin, I tried like this:

```
  data = rand(100,1);
  i = length(data);
  n = hist(data, i);
  min_number = 7;   % minimum no. in each bin
  for j = 1:length(n)
     if n(j) < min_number
      i = i-1;
      n = hist(data,i);
     end
  end
```

But I am making some mistakes. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is wrong with Matlab's [`hist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html) function? It has all your information.

Comment: yes, but I want at least 7 elements in each bin. And it requires playing again and again with the number of bin if the no. of elements in a bin is less than 7. So, I guess I have to use some if-else somewhere.

Comment: can you please clarify "*But I am making some mistakes*" - do you get error messages? If yes, include them in the question. If the code does not do what you expect it to - describe that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code based on your own will do it:

```
data = rand(100,1);
i = length(data);
n = hist(data, i);
min_number = 7;   % minimum no. in each bin
while any(n < min_number)
     i = i-1;
     [n bins] = hist(data,i);
end

figure
bar(bins,n)
```

(a). number of bin

```
nbin = length(bins);
```

(b). data in each bin

- if you mean the number of counts per bin, that is returned directly by `hist` as `n` of course
- if you mean, a pointer from each data entry to its corresponding bin, I would recommend modifying `hist` (make a copy as your own personal version) to return the output of `histc` which is run within `hist`, or calling `histc` after figuring out the edges of the histogram.

(c). bin size for each bin

`hist` uses equally sized bins, thus

```
binsize = bins(2)-bins(1)
```

(d). bin start & bin end for each bin

```
binedges = [bins'-binsize/2 bins'+binsize/2]
```